# Javascript arrays with email address and password

Tags: javascript, arrays

I work with PHP and I am more familiar with it. I have tried an array in Javascript but keep getting a syntax error and I am not sure why. I have Googled arrays and I do not seem to get the answer.

Here is my array of Users in Javascript:

```
var users = [
    [
      emailAddress: 'david@email.com',
      password: 'secretCat';
    ],
    [
      emailAddress: 'john@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatTwo';
    ],

    [
      emailAddress: 'chloe@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatThree';
    ],

    [
       emailAddress: 'susan@email.com',
       password: 'secretCatFour';
    ],

];
```

Am I supposed to do it differently in Javascript?

Comment: Use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate the syntax. *Hint:* -  An array only contains values, rather than key values.

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript are lists of values. To have key/value pairs, you’ll want an object, and object literals use curly braces `{emailAddress: 'susan@email.com', …}`

Comment: @gurvinder372: JavaScript object literals aren’t the same as JSON.

Comment: The colons are invalid. Just remove them.

Answer (score 4):

You need an array of objects, you can't use `name: value` structure as array item, should be like :

```
var users = [
    {
      emailAddress: 'david@email.com',
      password: 'secretCat'
    },
    {
      emailAddress: 'john@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatTwo'
    },

    {
      emailAddress: 'chloe@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatThree'
    },

    {
       emailAddress: 'susan@email.com',
       password: 'secretCatFour'
    }
];
```

By removing the extra `;` and using the object braces `{}`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Array in Javascript cannot replicate Associative array in PHP.

For your use case you would have to have array of objects like this.

```
var users = [
    {
      emailAddress: 'david@email.com',
      password: 'secretCat';
    },
    {
      emailAddress: 'john@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatTwo';
    },
    {
      emailAddress: 'chloe@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatThree';
    },
    {
       emailAddress: 'susan@email.com',
       password: 'secretCatFour';
    }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of objects instead:

```js
var users = [
    {
      emailAddress: 'david@email.com',
      password: 'secretCat',
    },
    {
      emailAddress: 'john@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatTwo'
    },

    {
      emailAddress: 'chloe@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatThree'
    },

    {
       emailAddress: 'susan@email.com',
       password: 'secretCatFour'
    },

 ];
 
 users.forEach((user, index) => {
 
  console.log("INDEX   :", index);
  console.log("EMAIL   :", user.emailAddress);
  console.log("PASSWORD:", user.password);
  
 
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports associative arrays. But in JavaScript you can use object to reflect the behavior of associative array. Like this:

```js
var users = [
    {
      emailAddress: 'david@email.com',
      password: 'secretCat'
    },
    {
      emailAddress: 'john@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatTwo'
    },

    {
      emailAddress: 'chloe@email.com',
      password: 'secretCatThree'
    },

    {
       emailAddress: 'susan@email.com',
       password: 'secretCatFour'
    }

     ];

    console.log('SrNo.\tEmail\t\tPassword');
    users.forEach((item,index)=>{
    console.log(index+1+'\t'+item.emailAddress+'\t'+item.password)
    })
```